# Keras Load Model.h5 works fine locally, but it fails when deployed to heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, heroku, keras

I recently took an AI class and worked on a model, along with making a web app for it using Streamlit.

I saved the model as `model.h5` and load it using `keras.models.load_model("model.h5")`.  When I run the web app locally or on Google Colab, it works perfectly, however when I deploy it to Heroku and put all the files in a GitHub repository, it gives me this error:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 350, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = load_model(os.path.join("./", "model.h5"))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py", line 205, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 108, in load
    meta_graph_def = tf.__internal__.saved_model.parse_saved_model(path).meta_graphs[0]
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 118, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError(
```

From what I can see, I think it's looking for the saved model in pb format rather than in the h5 format.  I tried using pb format but wasn't sure how exactly it worked, and it takes longer to download and upload anyway.  I also tried doing `load_model("model.h5", compile=False)`, but that didn't fix it either.  I looked at some other stackoverflow posts, but most of those were different and didn't exactly have a fix for my problem.  I honestly have no idea how to get it to work.  I also have a .slugignore for the *.h5 file which I'm not sure does anything, but I have it because I think the slug size would be too large otherwise.  I deleted it, and I don't think it changed anything.  The heroku deployment still shows the same error.

In case it is needed, here is the code for loading the model:

```py
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import os
model = load_model("model.h5")
# Code for the UI goes here, it works fine
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you have the h5py library installed in heroku?

Comment: Yeah i do, it's in my requirements.txt

Comment: And does it import correctly? Because it needs the native HDF5 library.

Comment: yes, i have it in my requirements.txt as `h5py`